# Can I take an iMac desktop as a visitor to London?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I am traveling to the UK as a visitor. Can I take an iMac desktop with me to give as a gift to my daughter? Is there a customs declaration that I need to do? Do I need to pay any duty?

Comment: The duty (if any) payable is going to depend a little bit on what route you're travelling on, and whether you'll be carrying the computer as checked baggage, as well as the value of the device itself.

Comment: @origimbo Any duties or VAT or other taxes do not depend on whether goods are hand-carried or in checked luggage.

Comment: @mkennedy Under the normal rules, hand luggage gets its duty paid when it enters the EU, whereas duty on checked luggage is paid at the final destination. That's why this is also route dependent.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend against this. You will have to pay 20% VAT. But then the computer won't have a British keyboard, it won't have a British power plug, it won't have British consumer rights, and unless it is a MacMini, it will cost a lot of money to transport it, and there will be significant risk of damage. Check the prices for purchasing the computer in the UK and your own country.

Answer (score 2):

This is an import, and as such is subject to VAT and import duties, as the value most certainly exceeds the thresholds for duty-free imports (unless it’s really a very old one maybe).

Go through the red channel at customs. Expect to pay 20% VAT. There may be additional duties and costs. Bring the original invoice to justify the actual value.